# Disabled NPC Fallout New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

When I was doing Honest Heart DLC, Waking Cloud was my NPC as those who've done the DLC know. But for some reason I went in console and disabled her because she kept dying*. When I tried to re-enable her again I kept getting the message that I required a message. Then when I typed `enable <ref id>` and `enable <base id>` it said unkown variable. That was a couple weeks ago. Fast foward to now - I have E-DE and Boone as my companions and I still for some reason have Waking Clouds perk, the only thing wrong is that when I pull up World Map on the Pip-boy it shows her marker there but whenever I go to it she's not there and plus when I go TFC through console she's nowhere to be found. What do I do?

*at the time I didn't know her base id in order to make her essential for the time being.

Comment: how did you disable her if you didn't know her base id? Did you use her ref id?

Comment: Can you go to the Gun Runners shop and disband all companions?

Comment: yeah i used the ID the comes up when you just click her. so i used her ref ID instead of her base ID... i haven't thought of the gun runners thing to disable all companions i'll try that